# multiplexer 8x1 with 4 2x1 multiplexer& 1 4x1

Tags: vhdl

the code is show multiplexer 8x1 using 2x1 and 4x1. i try this code put is show an error that say  There is no default binding for component "mux8x1". (Port "I" is not on the entity) and i don't understand where its my fault in the code i check it again and again dont found something wrong if some one can help me i will be grateful that

```
-- Code your design here
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

--declaration for 8x1
entity mux8x1 is   
    port( I : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); -- input that need 8x1
           s: in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0); --is the enable
           Y: out std_logic -- output of 8x1 is the output
    );
end mux8x1;

architecture behavioral of mux8x1 is
    signal f0,f1,f2,f3 : std_logic;
begin
    process(I,S)
    begin
        if s(0)='0' then 
            f0<=I(7);
            f1<=I(5);
            f2<=I(3);
            f3<=I(1);
        else 
            f0<=I(6);
            f1<=I(4);
            f2<=I(2);
            f3<=I(0);
        end if;

        if (s(1)='0' and s(0)='0')then
            Y<=f0;
            if (s(1)='0' and s(0)='1')then
                Y<=f1;
                if (s(1)='1' and s(0)='0')then
                    Y<=f2;
                    if (s(1)='1' and s(0)='1')then
                        Y<=f3;
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end behavioral;
```

Comment: Do you have a testcase? The error may come because of a difference between the 2 files. And don't you have entities for the mux2 and 4 that you would be supposed to use?

Comment: I did a little code beautification for you (just fixed the indents). Do you see your error now?

Comment: @mfro - No. IEEE Std 1076-2008 Annex I "**binding**: The process of associating a design entity and, optionally, an architecture with an instance of a component. A binding can be specified in an explicit or a default binding indication. (3.4, 7.3.2, 7.3.3, 14.4.3.3, 14.5.4)." A problem with a default binding indication can only occur where there is design entity associated with an instance, which isn't shown here.

Comment: @user1155120 : probably an XY problem? The TO does not need to fiddle with binding as long as he appears to have serious flaws in his logic

Comment: so what is the problem and it appears me the no default binding for component "mux8x1". help me to understand exactly what is wrong with me code and expplain me if you can because i just start to learn for that language and i don't know very many

Comment: The problem "which isn't shown here" can't be solved without a [mcve].

Comment: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3uH4 here is the code in EDA playground please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
ARCHITECTURE behavior OF mux8x1 IS 
   COMPONENT mux8x1 is
```

Your testbench must have another name than the tested entity/component, that's all!
Rename your testbench as mux8x1_tb
Which proves you should have put the testbench code here for us to help you...

Comment: thnks for the response, this link is my code that shows  the testbench check if you can please https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3uH4